# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {block}). Help please :(

Tags: reactjs, redux

[ENG]
I just can't figure out what the mistake is.

`Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {block})`

I looked at solutions to similar errors but nothing helped

[RU]
Я просто не могу понять, в чем ошибка.

`Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {block})`

Я смотрел решения подобных ошибок, но ничего не помогло

***index.js***

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducer from "./reducer";
import App from "./App";

const store = createStore(reducer);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    rootElement
);
```

***reducer***

```
const initialState = {
    block: [
        {
            category: "Name",
            color: "AB14C3",
            list: [
                {
                    imgLink: "http",
                    title: "Named",
                    discription: "lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem"
                },
                {
                    imgLink: "http",
                    title: "Named",
                    discription: "lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem"
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "TEST":
            return {state};
        default:
            return {state}
    }
};
export default reducer;
```

***Action.js***

```
const Click = () => {
    return { type: "TEST" };
};
export { Click };
```

***App.js***

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
const App = ({initState}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{initState}</h1>
        </div>
    );
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        initState: state
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

[ENG]
Thanks for attention
[RU]
Спасибо за внимание

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский язык

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это неверно:

```
<h1>{initState}</h1> // Это объект
```

Попробуйте это увидеть:

```
<h1>{JSON.stringify(initState)}</h1>
```

Вам нужно преобразовать его в [JSX](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html), используя `.map`

прочтите следующее: https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#javascript-expressions-as-children

Comment: [ENG] Thank you, you helped me figure it out! [RU]Спасибо, вы помогли мне разобраться!